# Postgres query show nullable field

Tags: sql, postgresql, sql-null

I have two tables:

```
Table A
id, name,   b_id,   c_id
1   aaa     1       1
2   bbb     2       1
3   ccc     NULL    1
```

```
Table B
id, bb_id
1   5
2   6
```

And i try this query:

```
SELECT a.id, a.name
FROM a
LEFT JOIN b ON b.id = a.b_id
WHERE b.bb_id = 5
```

I want to get such a result:

```
1, aaa
3, ccc
```

Or if bb_id = 6:

```
2, bbb
3, ccc
```

But my result only one row without nullable row. How to achieve this result?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hmmm . . . You seem to want `NULL` to many any `bb_id` value:

```
SELECT a.id, a.name
FROM a LEFT JOIN
     b
     ON b.id = a.b_id
WHERE b.bb_id = 5 OR a.b_id IS NULL;
```

Comment: Yes, of cause :)